# Is there a way to really pickle compiled regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, regex, pickle

I have a python console application that contains 300+ regular expressions.  The set of regular expressions is fixed for each release.  When users run the app, the entire set of regular expressions will be applied anywhere from once (a very short job) to thousands of times (a long job).

I would like to speed up the shorter jobs by compiling the regular expressions up front, pickle the compiled regular expressions to a file, and then load that file when the application is run.

The python re module is efficient and the regex compilation overhead is quite acceptable for long jobs.  For short jobs, however, it is a large proportion of the overall run-time.  Some users will want to run many small jobs to fit into their existing workflows. Compiling the regular expressions takes about 80ms.  A short job might take 20ms-100ms excluding regular expression compilation.  So for short jobs, the overhead can be 100% or more.  This is with Python27 under both Windows and Linux.

The regular expressions must be applied with the DOTALL flag, so need to be compiled prior to use. A large compilation cache clearly doesn't help in this instances.  As some have pointed out, the default method to serialise the compiled regular expression doesn't actually do much.

The re and sre modules compile the patterns into a little custom language with its own opcodes and some auxiliary data structures (e.g., for charsets used in an expression).  The pickle function in re.py takes the easy way out.  It is:

```
def _pickle(p):
    return _compile, (p.pattern, p.flags)

copy_reg.pickle(_pattern_type, _pickle, _compile)
```

I think that a good solution to the problem would be an update to the definition of _pickle in re.py that actually pickled the compiled pattern object.  Unfortunately, this goes beyond my python skills.  I bet, however, that someone here knows how to do it.

I realise that I am not the first person to ask this question - but perhaps you can be the first person to give an accurate and useful response to it!

Your advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With this many regexen, consider bumping re._MAXCACHE up from its default value of 100.

Comment: @user489276: You didn't actually ask a question. You didn't actually supply much useful information. Here are some questions for you: Exactly how long does it take to compile your 300+ regexes on what version of Python on what platform? Are all 300+ regexes used in a job?

Comment: "How to pickle compiled regular expressions in python" is lacking a punctuation mark, but is still recognizable as a question.

Comment: If the set is fixed for each release, and the regular expressions take an unacceptable time, then I would replace them with a proper parser.

Comment: To be clear - this is an excellent problem for regular expressions.  The pattern matching is sufficiently fast. The goal is to eliminate unnecessary run-time overhead.

Comment: In the state that it currently is, this is an excellent first question. Welcome to the community, we hope you stick around.

Answer (score 12):

OK, this isn't pretty, but it might be what you want.  I looked at the sre_compile.py module from Python 2.6, and ripped out a bit of it, chopped it in half, and used the two pieces to pickle and unpickle compiled regexes:

```
import re, sre_compile, sre_parse, _sre
import cPickle as pickle

# the first half of sre_compile.compile    
def raw_compile(p, flags=0):
    # internal: convert pattern list to internal format

    if sre_compile.isstring(p):
        pattern = p
        p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
    else:
        pattern = None

    code = sre_compile._code(p, flags)

    return p, code

# the second half of sre_compile.compile
def build_compiled(pattern, p, flags, code):
    # print code

    # XXX: <fl> get rid of this limitation!
    if p.pattern.groups > 100:
        raise AssertionError(
            "sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups"
            )

    # map in either direction
    groupindex = p.pattern.groupdict
    indexgroup = [None] * p.pattern.groups
    for k, i in groupindex.items():
        indexgroup[i] = k

    return _sre.compile(
        pattern, flags | p.pattern.flags, code,
        p.pattern.groups-1,
        groupindex, indexgroup
        )

def pickle_regexes(regexes):
    picklable = []
    for r in regexes:
        p, code = raw_compile(r, re.DOTALL)
        picklable.append((r, p, code))
    return pickle.dumps(picklable)

def unpickle_regexes(pkl):
    regexes = []
    for r, p, code in pickle.loads(pkl):
        regexes.append(build_compiled(r, p, re.DOTALL, code))
    return regexes

regexes = [
    r"^$",
    r"a*b+c*d+e*f+",
    ]

pkl = pickle_regexes(regexes)
print pkl
print unpickle_regexes(pkl)
```

I don't really know if this works, or if it speeds things up.  I know it prints a list of regexes when I try it.  It might be very specific to version 2.6, I also don't know that.

Comment: This looks very promising.  I'm looking forward to trying it out and will report back on the results.

Comment: +1. Note: I remember reading somewhere that the reason regexes are not stored in their compiled form is inter-Python-version compatibility (the stored re form can and does change between Python versions), so yes, you're probably right that this might be a 2.6-only solution.

Answer (score 9):

As others have mentioned, you can simply pickle the compiled regex.  They will pickle and unpickle just fine, and be usable.  However, it doesn't look like the pickle actually contains the result of compilation.  I suspect you will incur the compilation overhead again when you use the result of the unpickling.

```
>>> p.dumps(re.compile("a*b+c*"))
"cre\n_compile\np1\n(S'a*b+c*'\np2\nI0\ntRp3\n."
>>> p.dumps(re.compile("a*b+c*x+y*"))
"cre\n_compile\np1\n(S'a*b+c*x+y*'\np2\nI0\ntRp3\n."
```

In these two tests, you can see the only difference between the two pickles is in the string. Apparently compiled regexes don't pickle the compiled bits, just the string needed to compile it again.

But I'm wondering about your application overall: compiling a regex is a fast operation, how short are your jobs that compiling the regex is significant?  One possibility is that you are compiling all 300 regexes, and then only using one for a short job.  In that case, don't compile them all up front.  The re module is very good at using cached copies of compiled regexes, so you generally don't have to compile them yourself, just use the string form.  The re module will lookup the string in a dictionary of compiled regexes, so grabbing the compiled form yourself only saves you a dictionary look up.  I may be totally off-base, sorry if so.

Comment: You are correct that the pickle does not contain the result of the compilation.  This is the reason for asking the question.  I've updated the original post to indicate that the regex compilation introduces up to 100% overhead on short jobs (which can be numerous).

Comment: I've previously done profiling which shows that with just one regular expression, compiling it before use is significantly faster than using a string. I'm not sure how efficient regex caching really is.

Answer (score 3):

Just compile as you go - re module will cache the compiled re's even if you dont.  Bump the re._MAXCACHE up to 400 or 500, the short jobs will only compile the re's they need, and the long jobs benefit from a big fat cache of compiled expressions - everybody's happy!

Comment: Not if a short job uses **all** the regexes once.

Comment: Even a short job requires all regexes to be applied.

Comment: My mistake - I mistook "short job" to mean "only needs some of the regexes" - I'll try to read the whole question next time before answering.

Answer (score 2):

Some observations and musings:

You don't need to compile to get the effect of the re.DOTALL flag (or any other flag)-- all you need to do is insert `(?s)`  at the start of the pattern string ... re.DOTALL -> re.S -> the s in (?s). Do a Ctrl-F search for `sux` (sic) in the [re syntax docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

80ms seems a very short time, even when multiplied by "many" (how many??) short jobs.

Does each job require a new Python process to be started? If so, isn't 80ms small compared with process startup and shutdown overhead? Otherwise, please explain why it is not possible, when a user wants to run "many" small jobs, to do the re.compiles once per batch of jobs.

Comment: 1. (?s) - instead of the compile flag. That is very helpful.  I has missed this in the docs.  2. The process startup and basic module load takes 390ms, so 80ms adds over 20%. 3. A lot might be tens of thousands.

Comment: @Adam: Instead of trying to make the 80ms per job vanish, concentrate on making the 390+80=470ms per job vanish. I ask again: please explain why it is not possible, when a user wants to run "many" small jobs, to do the re.compiles once per batch of jobs.

Comment: Tens of thousands * eighty milliseconds = eighties of seconds -- maybe a couple of minutes.  Does not seem like a lot in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar case (where every time some input needs to be run through ALL of the regexes), I had to split the Python script in a master-slave setup using *nix sockets; the first time the script is called, the master —doing all time-expensive regex compilations— starts up and the slave for that and all subsequent invokations exchanges data with the master. The master stays idle maximum N seconds.

In my case, this master/slave setup was found to be faster in all occasions than the straightforward way (many invokations against relatively little data every time; also, it had to be a script because it is called from an external application without any Python bindings). I don't know whether this would apply to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and instead of patching python's `re` module I opted to create a long running regex "service" instead. Basic code appended below. Please note: It is *not* designed to handle multiple clients in parallel, i.e. the server is only available once a client has closed the connection.

**server**

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
import re

class RegexService(object):
    patternsByRegex = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.patternsByRegex = {}

    def processMessage(self, message):
        regex = message.get('regex')
        result = {"error": None}
        if regex == None:
            result["error"] = "no regex in message - something is wrong with your client"
            return result
        text = message.get('text')
        pattern = self.patternsByRegex.get(regex)
        if pattern == None:
            print "compiling previously unseen regex: %s" %(regex)
            pattern = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
            self.patternsByRegex[regex] = pattern
        if text == None:
            result["error"] = "no match"
            return result
        match = pattern.match(text)
        result["matchgroups"] = None
        if match == None:
            return result
        result["matchgroups"] = match.groups()
        return result

workAddress = ('localhost', 6000)
resultAddress = ('localhost', 6001)
listener = Listener(workAddress, authkey='secret password')
service = RegexService()
patterns = {}
while True:
    connection = listener.accept()
    resultClient = Client(resultAddress, authkey='secret password')
    while True:
        try:
            message = connection.recv()
            resultClient.send(service.processMessage(message))
        except EOFError:
            resultClient.close()
            connection.close()
            break
listener.close()
```

**testclient**

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener


workAddress = ('localhost', 6000)
resultAddress = ('localhost', 6001)
regexClient = Client(workAddress, authkey='secret password')
resultListener = Listener(resultAddress, authkey='secret password')
resultConnection = None

def getResult():
    global resultConnection
    if resultConnection == None:
        resultConnection = resultListener.accept()
    return resultConnection.recv()

regexClient.send({
    "regex": r'.*'
})
print str(getResult())
regexClient.send({
    "regex": r'.*',
    "text": "blub"
})
print str(getResult())
regexClient.send({
    "regex": r'(.*)',
    "text": "blub"
})
print str(getResult())
resultConnection.close()
regexClient.close()
```

**output of test client run 2 times**

```
$ python ./regexTest.py 
{'error': 'no match'}
{'matchgroups': (), 'error': None}
{'matchgroups': ('blub',), 'error': None}
$ python ./regexTest.py 
{'error': 'no match'}
{'matchgroups': (), 'error': None}
{'matchgroups': ('blub',), 'error': None}
```

**output of service process during both test runs**

```
$ python ./regexService.py
compiling previously unseen regex: .*
compiling previously unseen regex: (.*)
```

Answer (score -2):

As long as you create them on program start, the pyc file will cache them.  You don't need to result to pickling.

Comment: Well, no. Neither `pickle` nor `marshal` (and therefore the pyc file) store compiled regexes. That's the whole issue raised by the question.