# Recognizing dictionary words in a string

Tags: python, regex, string, search

I'm writing a program to assess a password's strength. One function in my program takes the entered password and compares it against a massive list of words and passwords.

This piece of code is a binary search that sees if an entered password is in the password list.

```
with io.open('PasswordList.txt', encoding='latin-1') as myfile:
        data = myfile.readlines()
        low = 0
        high = (len(data)-1)
        while (low <= high) and not Found:
            mid = int((low+high)/2)
            if data[mid].rstrip() == Password:
                Found = True
                break
            elif Password < str(data[mid]):
                high = mid - 1
            elif Password > str(data[mid]):
                low = mid + 1
```

This piece of code strips all numbers from the password, turns it into common letters and checks it against the list again. "Password123" would turn into "password", and "password" is in the list.

```
SimplePassword = ''.join([i for i in Password if not i.isdigit()])
SimplePassword = SimplePassword.lower()

if not Found:
        with io.open('final.txt', encoding='latin-1') as myfile:
            data = myfile.readlines()
            low = 0
            high = (len(data)-1)
            while (low <= high) and not Found:
                mid = int((low+high)/2)
                if data[mid].rstrip() == SimplePassword:
                    PartiallyFound = True
                    break
                elif SimplePassword < str(data[mid]):
                    high = mid - 1
                elif SimplePassword > str(data[mid]):
                    low = mid + 1
```

I wanted to take this further by writing some code that could recognize names or words in a string. For example, the word "john" is in the list and the word "smith' is in the list. However, an entered password "JohnSmith123" would fly under the radar.

How can I make it so that I split apart a string into separate words? One approach I was thinking about was appending the letters in between capital letters to an array, then checking each element in that array individually.

There has to be a better approach though. Is there some way to see if an entered password can be constructed from variations of words inside a large wordlist?

Comment: Peter Norvig has a really nice iPython notebook writeup on the topic of word analysis. Task 5 is Word Segmentation. http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

You could just test

```
badness = 0
for word in wordlist:
    if word in passwordString and len(word) > badness:
        badness = len(word)
```

That way, the word Password would get hit by:

- Password
- word
- pass
- etc

But only "password" would actually apply.

Comment: @Kos: I just edited his answer to convert it to Python.

Comment: Yes. You could add logic to make it stop if it finds a word that matches over a certain percentage of the entire password. That would speed it up a little. But if you want to see if any of the words are in the password, then that will take some time...

Comment: @Kos - Imagine a spell checker that went through 130,000 words every time you typed a letter. Use the Ternary tree regex generator from my link. Or, give me your data, and I'll generate one for you.

Comment: @Kos - Ever see a 175,000 word ternary tree dictionary regex ? [here it is](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt). Fast as lightning.

Comment: That is an immense expression. I don't have windows to use your tool to create a regular expression. I will send you my data

Comment: Couldn't create a PasteBin, data too large

Answer (score 1):

`from variations of words inside a large wordlist`

There is a tool you can use to construct a regex *Trie* from your
word list.
You just paste in all the variations into a text box, and it pumps out
a full blown regex trie.

This is probably the fastest lookup there is.

The tool is available in the trial version.

Screen shot [Tool](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg).
[App](http://www.regexformat.com) runs on Windows only.

Location from main menu is Tools->Ternary Tree

***Benchmark***

[Regex used](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt)
[Samples](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/)

```
Regex1:
Completed iterations:   1  /  1     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   174939
Elapsed Time:    600.30 s,   600296.36 ms,   600296365 µs
```

Target Sample: All 174,939 words that the regex represents (in random order)

Sample Analysis:

```
    174,939  words matched / iteration
  x   1,000  iterations
------------------------------
 174,939,000 total words matched
  /      600 total seconds
------------------------------
     291,565 words matched / second         <<<
  /    1,000 miliseconds / second
------------------------------
         292 words matched / milisecond     <<<
```

Comment: Hi. You know what I need to do but I'm having trouble trying to implement this all. I'm not sure how to actually use that immense expression. And I can't use the tool unfortunately, I'm on Mac.

Comment: @Kos - Borrow a pc. Or give me a link to your words/strings and I'll make one for you.

Comment: Actually using the expression is easy. It's just a regex. You can make it case insensitive, use boundaries, put it into an assertion, or however you need to use it. The trick is to compile it only once when the program starts up. Then you can just use it over and over to do searching or matching.

Comment: Hi, I'm unable to borrow a PC unfortunately. The word list is quite large, find it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B31gs4C4jMl7RTJBN3JFQTBSd1U. 

I'm still not quite sure what exactly a regex is, or even how to integrate it into Python code. I've done some research and my understanding is that all the different symbols next to characters denote different kinds of variations?

Comment: @Kos - Looks like its about 10 million last names from a phone book. Anyway .. The regexes are [HERE](http://www.regexformat.com/sln/kos/). Take them off quick because they will be deleted soon. `FT0001-FT0048` The `.rxf` extension is the regexformat file. The `.txt` extension is the broken up text part @ 2.5 MB/ea. The `.rx.txt` is the part converted into a regex @ 900KB/ea. 48 separate regexes make up the _total_. Try one out to see if Python will take a regex of that size. If so, you create 48 separate compiled regex on startup. Do a for loop using each regex on the password.

Comment: You really only need the FT0001-FT0048 `.rx.txt` files.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I managed to grab all the .rx.txt files. I'm still really confused on how to implement this hahahaha. Will these trees allow me to look for variations like Horse, hOrse, hoRse? 
So if the entered password is "hoRse" and there is a word in the list "horse", it can match the two? Or "Horse123" to horse? And "Hor$e" to horse?

Comment: Also, how would I use the regex on the password? It's embarrassing but I've never used regexes before and Google isn't helping me much

Comment: @Kos - I tried to tell you before, the Tool is very customizable. I just did a general case insensitive and group around the whole thing `(?I)(?:...)` There is a wildcard character option as well. But, yes it will match any form of _horse_. The `Hor$e` is a permutation. I said before, include all permutations. Also, I didn't add any boundary conditions so it will match 555`HoRse`999 if that were the string.

Comment: You have the regex's, learn up on usage of Python regexes and try it out. The size of the regex would be my first concern, do a simple test to see if Python takes a single 900KB one, or if it does, then it is limited by only memory available. I could have made a single regex that is about 40MB that includes them all but I broke it up. So, you would make an array of regex objects, 48 of them. In a for loop, use each rxarr[I] on the password to get the matches. On each match put it into a string array, do analysis when the for loop ends.

Comment: If it takes the 900KB regex, I'll combine them for you as a test. Initially though, each regex will take a second to compile. Expect about a 40 second wait on startup. After compiled though, it will work on passwords very fast.

Comment: I am now trying to apply the regex, will let you know if it takes 900kb. Why such a long wait on startup? Would it be possible to pre-compile the regexes somehow? So that all we have to do is load them into memory on startup or something instead of compiling each time?

Comment: You can check of Python can serialize objects to disk. It takes so long because it has to setup a dfa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105725/discussion-between-kos-and-sln).

Comment: @Kos - Ok, one big regex about 42MB. There were about 29 Unicode characters in the file. I had to convert them to Pythons regex Unicode notation `\u0000`. So you have to use the `re.UNICODE` options flag to use this regex. There are 2 new files in that same location. `FT_all_rx_README.txt` explains how to use the regex (flag option and compiling it). `FT_all_rx_Unotation.txt` is the file containing the regex. Because of the Unicode characters, those other regex text files may be invalid. Let me know how this works.

Comment: Hey sln,

I wasn't able to get to these files in time before the website went down :( I especially need the FT_all_rx_README.txt file. I've combine the regexes myself but I am having trouble making them work fast enough without pre-compiling ...

Comment: You're literally the only person that understands the problem I'm having !

Comment: @Kos - Hey, how did you make out? I put the two files back there. I have to take them off asap. `FT_all_rx_README.txt` and `FT_all_rx_Unotation.txt` Both files are in strictly ASCII text. Like I said the all_unotation.txt is the combined regex, it is to be read as ascii text. It is _all_ of it and all you need. You have to compile this ahead of time, then you can use it in a loop. Let me know when you dnload them, so I can remove them. My friend there says I can only do this temporarily, and can't use it as a repository. `Be sure to 'save target as' when you download them`.

Comment: If you have to use it all the time, you could always create a separate service background process and ipc to it with the password.

Comment: I grabbed the regex, thanks! Were you able to compile it? I used re.compile(regex, re.UNICODE) on it but it's been running for the past 3 minutes. If I actually manage to compile it, I have to figure out how to serialize it because I can't implement it into my program if the user needs to wait 3+ minutes before using it. Any ideas on how I can approach serializing it? Pickle won't work ...

Comment: @Kos - No, I don't have or know Python. I did test the regex on regexformat7 app, it runs fine, although takes a minute to load. Once it compiles, it finds 300,000 words per second though, in benchmark tests.

Comment: I guess you could try to make a service out of it. How, I don't know though.

Comment: I do know in Perl you can serialize objects, don't know about Python though.

Comment: I found a python 2.6 solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037339/is-there-a-way-to-really-pickle-compiled-regular-expressions-in-python. I guess I can work on translating it to Python 3

Comment: @Kos - And one of those thread answers shows how to make a service of it. Did it complete the compile ?