# Getting a regex trie to run faster?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, trie

I have a 50mb regex trie that I'm using to split phrases apart.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import io
import re

with io.open('REGEXES.rx.txt', encoding='latin-1') as myfile:
        regex = myfile.read()


while True == True:
    Password = input("Enter a phrase to be split: ")

    Words = re.findall(regex, Password)

    print(Words)
```

Since the regex is so large, this takes forever!

Here is the code I'm trying now, with re.compile(TempRegex):

```
import io
import re

with io.open('REGEXES.rx.txt', encoding='latin-1') as myfile:
        TempRegex = myfile.read()

regex = re.compile(TempRegex)

while True == True:
    Password = input("Enter a phrase to be split: ")

    Words = re.findall(regex, Password)

    print(Words)
```

What I'm trying to do is I'm trying to check to see if an entered phrase is a combination of names. For example, the phrase "johnsmith123" to return ['john', 'smith', '123']. The regex file was created by a tool from a word list of every first and last name from Facebook. I want to see if an entered phrase is a combination of words from that wordlist essentially ... If johns and mith are names in the list, then I would want "johnsmith123" to return ['john', 'smith', '123', 'johns', 'mith'].

Comment: A 50 MB regex will probably always be slow. Honestly, I have no idea how to even construct something on that scale or how it would be used. Can't you do some filtering first to reduce its size? The longest one I've ever seen before is [this one](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), and at 6kB, it's already a monster.

Comment: A regex this large is very unusual, and almost certainly not the right solution to any problem. Could you post, say, the first 400 chars of your regex?

Comment: from your syntax it's clear you are beginner in Python. It's ok but without proper code we can not help you. Why are you using io.open - use just open. Also - why the regex is in file ? Show it please.

Comment: A 50mb regular expression in order to parse short phrases entered by a user? This all sounds incredibly strange. Are you really searching for a 50 million character _pattern_, or are you searching for a list of word separated by pipes?

Comment: Here is a slice of the regex file: 
`"?i)(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!(?:!!?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?|666666!!!|gerard!!!|sara)?|\$,%n86|'nc2|\(,0o70|1331xxx|23lt9i|71\*6l|8558!!|@#\$%\^|blingbling|cs\.y\*|jed02\?|php1|t(?:echno|urbo)|urdead|w\.0xv|zzi#)|"(?:"\)rl|#\(67h|'0v#|34b%|e27\)!|selm|y\)7n1%)|#(?:!0xmt|%&\*\^\$@|1,m-z%|8z!p&|9h\$tgy|d/lqvp|ff"!9k|r"9ec|t'v9|wdm\.)|\$(?:4i69\)|f\*qgd/|v(?:%lhvp|r7y0a))|%(?:'n0y%|5ns9,l|6effh|exx3|t/q1uk)|&(?:\$\*50"1|1hebbj|b\.ne4|d4yj7|f(?:0\*hec|66af)|l#dm\)9|qj76'|r8d4w|xtxy)|'(?:!\.hcv|/\)u#tw|2\*tin|43at5|d3\$,|e509|ij\$s`

Comment: You must be using some sort of tool to generate that. There's no way a human could comprehend it. How did you create this expression?

Comment: What I'm doing is I'm trying to see if an entered phrase contains a name. For example, I want the input "johnsmith123" to return ['john', 'smith', '123']. The regex file comes from every first and last name from Facebook.

Comment: Yes, I used a tool

Comment: I'm surprised this even finishes 0_o

Comment: How do you know that "johnsmith123" is someone with a first name of "john"? What if their first name is "johns" and his last name is "mith"?

Comment: If johns and mith are names , then I would want it to return them too. All possible combinations of names from inside the name list

Comment: Any idea how I can implement this thing ? It's part of a bigger program that I'm writing and it's essential. I tried a smaller implementation with a 1mb regex and it worked ... the only difference is now with the larger regex, it takes too long to even get to the input part

Comment: Really go for another approach - get a good database with names and use this one instead of monstrous regexes.

Comment: @Kos just because something works for a small sample doesn't mean it's viable when scaled up.

Comment: Please. Everyone is telling you that this is unfeasible. Your best bet is to ask another question detailing your problem, your current solution and the problems with it. You might be able to solve the your problem this way using a smaller regex, but regex complexity can grow exponentially (even infinitely) with size. If you indeed have a trie of the information you need to check, there should be a faster solution. Also, please note that "regex" and "trie" are words that do not really share the same context.

Comment: As several people have said, you probably shouldn't be using regexes for this problem.  A hammer is a fine tool if you want to build a bookcase, it isn't up to the task if you want to build a skyscraper.  In this analogy, regexes are hammers and it sounds like you want to build a skyscraper.  If you ask a question about what you are trying to do instead of your specific approach, we may be able to point you to a better tool.  This is a perfect example of [the xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that regex is the way to go here. It seems to me that all you are trying to do is to find a list of all of the substrings of a given string that happen to be names.

If the user's input is a password or passphrase, that implies a relatively short string. It's easy to break that string up into the set of possible substrings, and then test that set against another set containing the names.

The number of substrings in a string of length *n* is *n(n+1)/2*. Assuming that no one is going to enter more than say 40 characters you are only looking at 820 substrings, many of which could be eliminated as being too short. Here is some code to do that:

```
def substrings(s, min_length=1):
    for start in range(len(s)):
        for length in range(min_length, len(s)-start+1):
            yield s[start:start+length]
```

So the problem then is loading the names into a suitable data structure. Your regex is 50MB, but considering the snippet that you showed in one of your comments, the amount of actual data is going to be a lot smaller than that due to the overhead of the regex syntax.

If you just used text files with one name per line you could do this:

```
names = set(word.strip().lower() for word in open('names.txt'))

def substrings(s, min_length=1):
    for start in range(len(s)):
        for length in range(min_length, len(s)-start+1):
            yield s[start:start+length]

s = 'johnsmith123'
print(sorted(names.intersection(substrings(s)))
```

Might give output:

```
['jo', 'john', 'johns', 'mi', 'smith']
```

I doubt that there will be memory issues given the likely small data set, but if you find that there's not enough memory to load the full data set at once you could look at using [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) with a simple table to store the names. This will be slower to query, but it will fit in memory.

Another way could be to use the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module to create a persistent dictionary with names as keys.

Answer (score -2):

Python's regex engine is not actually a regular expression, since it includes features such as lookbehind, capture groups, back references, and uses backtracking to match the leftmost valid branch instead of the longest.

If you use a true regex engine, you will almost always get better results if your regex does not require those features.

One of the most important qualities of a true regular expression is that it will *always* return a result in time proportional to the length of the input, without using *any* memory.

I've written one myself using a DFA implemented in C (but usable from python via cffi), which will have optimal asymptotic performance, but I haven't tried constant-factor improvements such as vectorization and assembly generation. I didn't make a generally usable API though since I only need to call it from within my library, but it shouldn't be too hard to figure out from the examples. (Note that search can be implemented as match with `.*` up front, then match backward, but for my purpose I would rather return a single character as an error token). [Link to my project](https://github.com/o11c/nicate/blob/master/src/mre.h)

You might also consider building the DFA offline and using it for multiple runs of your program - but this is what [`flex`](https://github.com/westes/flex/) does so there was no point in me doing that for my project, so maybe just use that if you're comfortable with C? Of course you'd almost certainly have to write a fair bit of custom C code to use my project anyway ...

Comment: His problem is probably the method of operation, not python's regex engine.

Comment: If there is a way to compile the regex into a DFA offline and load it into the problem, this would be a feasible approach. (Constructing an automaton from a regex might take `O(2^n)` time, where `n` is the regex length, but evaluating a dfn will take only `O(n)` time.)

Comment: @Bharel I'm not convinced of that actually. I don't think there's any faster way to pull out the `john` from `johnsmith` than a true RE.

Answer (score -3):

If you compile it, the regex patterns will be compiled into a bytecodes then run by a matching engine. If you don't compile it, it will load it over and over for the same regex whenever it is called. That's why compiled one is way faster if you are using same regex for multiple different records.

Comment: This is not true at all. Python caches the last regexes used meaning it will take the same time.

Comment: It is true, as you don't compile it, it will be re-read each time whenever regex is called and compiled again.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Even a compiled 50 MB regex will probably an unfeasible monstrosity.

Comment: You guys don't get the point. The point is "it will not be loaded and compiled over and over" when it is compiled and used.

Comment: @Gon Read the documentation for [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.compile) before stating incorrect facts. See the note. And as @Carsten says, 50 MB regex is just a bad idea.

Comment: @Bharel, from your link, read this carefully: "but using re.compile() and saving the resulting regular expression object for reuse is more efficient when the expression will be used several times in a single program."

Comment: @Gon Read the note. "Note: The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to re.compile() and the module-level matching functions are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions."

Comment: @Bharel, I don't get your point. State where I was wrong information according to you.

Comment: @Gon, In python, if you use only a small amount of regexes, passing the same regex to `re.findall()` will cost no extra time, as the compiled regex is cached. Considering the OP is using only one regex, it will always be cached.

Comment: Regular expression object! That's what I need! Can I save the regular expression object to disk and load it up for use? This way , I can run re.compile() on my trie, let it run overnight, and just use the saved object when I need to ??

Comment: @Bharel, can you point out what I have said is not true? Since you said "this is not true at all" and "before stating incorrect facts".

Comment: @Gon - That part: "If you don't compile it, it will load it over and over for the same regex whenever it is called"

Comment: @Bharel. I see, but you cannot call that as "incorrect" or "not true at all". Your assumption for very tiny regex is not the case here. Isn't it?

Comment: @Gon. Considering the fact there is only 1 regex, it is true. What matters is the count, not the length. It's a VERY large regex, but only 1.

Comment: @Bharel, if what you saying is true, then the author should feel any speed difference between his 1st and 2nd codes, isn't it? (since it's only 1 and cached)

Comment: @Gon, If what I say is true, the author should **not** feel any difference between his 1st and 2nd codes, correct.

Comment: Guys, I can't even record the different because the re.compile() takes too long to finish. I want to run it overnight and see what happens. Is there any way I can run the compilation process once and save the regular expression object created so that I don't have to compile every time I want to run the module?

Comment: @Kos, that's very interesting concept..  maybe serializing? (pickle)

Comment: @Kos, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037339/is-there-a-way-to-really-pickle-compiled-regular-expressions-in-python

Comment: What @Bharel is saying is that when you first call re.findall, python compiles the regex and caches the result.  The second time you call re.findall, python does not compile the regex and uses the already cached version instead.  It only does this for a small number of regexes - if you use a lot then you have to compile and store them yourself (the note is saying that the previous statement is only true for many regexes - unfortunately, it doesn't define "many").  This means that the 2nd call will be faster than the first, but that the third call won't be any faster than the 2nd.

Comment: Note that the first answer to the question that you linked to about pickling compiled regexes makes this same point about python caching the result of compiling.