# Finding names inside a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, search, trie

I'm trying to check an inputted string for names. The data I have available is every first and last name from Facebook.

What I want my program to do is take the input "johnsmith123" (for example) and return ['john', 'smith', '123']. If 'johns' and 'mith' are names in the list, I would want it to return ['john', 'smith', '123', 'johns', 'mith']. Basically: every possible combination from words in the list that can make up the entered phrase.

I know that regex tries are really, really fast for lookups. Using a tool called RegexFormat 7, I turned the wordlist into a 50mb regex trie.

Here is the code I am now trying to run, using that trie:

```
import io
import re

with io.open('REGEXES.rx.txt', encoding='latin-1') as myfile:
        TempRegex = myfile.read()

regex = re.compile(TempRegex)

while True == True:
    Password = input("Enter a phrase to be split: ")

    Words = re.findall(regex, Password)

    print(Words)
```

The program never reaches the input part. I am assuming it will take very long to compile such a large regex trie.

What I need to know is if there is some way to do this compilation process once, save the regular expression object to my disk, and just load the pre-compiled object to be used into the module instead of having to compile every time?

It is the compiling that is taking up so much time. I know that the search would actually happen quite quickly. If I can do the compilation process once, I can just run the compile overnight ...

If this is not feasible, what else can I do? The data I have available is a 100mb word list of every first and last name from Facebook, and a regex trie derived from that wordlist

Comment: In the example you provide, how is it determined what name goes before the `123` and all the possible names that come after?  Consider `jonnathonsmith123`, what should come first -- `jon`, `jonn`, `jonnathon`? Do you have separate lists for first and last names?  Or just first names?  What happens if no names match?

Comment: The order does not matter. If no names match, then the array will be empty. The problem I'm having is that I can't actually get the implementation to work fast enough. Python has to compile the regex trie every time and that takes forever; what I need to know is if I can somehow do this compilation process once and save the results to disk?

Comment: I was going to suggest pickling, but according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037339/is-there-a-way-to-really-pickle-compiled-regular-expressions-in-python) that doesn't work. The answer there suggests leaving a long-running process going which might be an option for you.

Comment: Apparently pickling doesn't work because importing the result of the pickle makes Python compile anyway

Comment: You need to use `regex = re.compile(TempRegex, re.UNICODE)` since the TempRegex uses `\uDDDD` in it's body. Also, if Python supports try/catch, put one around the re.compile, since I believe the regex is very large. Another thing is the regex is a trie, built from a ternary tree. So, in escence, it is a ternary tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm skeptical that a single massive regular expression is the best solution here.  A single hash table of all possible first names might be faster.

```
all_first_names = set(['dan', 'bob', 'danny'])

username = 'dannysmith123'

# Get "extra" parts of the username if they exist
m = re.match(r'^([a-zA-Z]+)(.*)$', username)
name, extra = m.group(1), m.group(2)

# Get a list of possible first/last name splits
# [('d', 'annysmith'), ('da', 'nnysmith'), ...]
name_splits = [(name[:i], name[i:]) for i in range(1, len(name)+1)]

# Check each one of these splits to see if the first name
# is present in the master first name list, if so, add it to
# the list of valid matches.
match_list = []
for ns in name_splits:
    if ns[0] in all_first_names:
        match_list.extend(ns)
        if extra:
            match_list.append(extra)
            extra = None
```

Comment: I agree a hash table is probably better. It looks like he wants to match if a name appears anywhere in the string though. He also listed `123` as a possible word in the list, so I don't think he wants to exclude non-alphabetical suffixes.

Comment: Hi, I don't get what 
`name, extra = m.group(1), m.group(2)` 
and
`if extra:
            match_list.append(extra)
            extra = None`

are doing? Can you explain their purpose to me please?

Otherwise, this seems like a partial solution to my problem. The reason it's not a full solution is because I want to be able to match names to anywhere in the string; and also more than two names ... the eventual goal is to recognize dictionary words too, so something like "HorseFenceJump" ...

Comment: The regex above will split the username on non-alpha characters, so `bobhope123` becomes `bobhope` and `123`.  `user123name` would become `user` and `123name`.  In the example you listed above you wanted the non-alpha ending portion of the username to be 3rd in the returned list.

Comment: @Kos So in the `HorseFenceJump` example, what would the returned list look like?

Comment: And what about `HorseFenceGarblegook`?  Where garblegook is not a valid word.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what he wants is `name_splits = [username[i:i+j] for i in xrange(len(username)) for j in xrange(1, len(username) - i + 1)]` and `match_list = [name for name in name_list if all_first_names.has_key(name)]`. Also if you have a minimum name length, you can optimize the `name_splits` some.